# want to sort grid coloum on load in ext js by default shorting on load

Tags: extjs

I tried to use :

```js
sortOnLoad: true, 
sorters: {
    property: 'Item1', 
    direction : 'DESC'
}
```

Property for sorting grid column on load but it is not working

Is there any other way?

Comment: Can u fiddle your code.Here is the working example of same https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5s&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your sorter on the store, not on the grid:

```
 stores: {
       allocations: {
            model: 'mine.model.Allocation',
            sorters: [{
                property: 'name',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }]
        }
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure you have remoteSort turned of since you are not doing server side sorting.

Comment: I made your fiddle work by also fixing your model definition:
     {name: 'lastpost', mapping: 'lastpost', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'time'}
You had timestamp as the format.

Answer (score 0):

go to main controller.js file write

```
storename.sort('dataindex','ASC');
```

after the code of page load